# How to Save the Captured Image to Internal Storage

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, local-storage

Hi Guys I would like to add an option in my Camera App where as the User Opens an App, a pop will appear with an option to where to save a captured images and pop up need to include the subfolders of camera default storage Folders and with an option to create new folder and rename option and then when hit enter, whatever he captures will be saved on same folder and Once he would like to save the images to next folder, Users should be able to choose from settings in app bar where when pressed will be shown the same pop up with an option to where to save a captured images with same subfolders.

My Main activity contains

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.sairamkrishna.myapplication" >
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
   <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      
      <activity
         android:name="com.example.sairamkrishna.myapplication.MainActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name" >
         
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
         
     </activity>
     
   </application>
</manifest>
```

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

```html
package com.example.sairamkrishna.myapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;

import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 100;
   public static final String ALLOW_KEY = "ALLOWED";
   public static final String CAMERA_PREF = "camera_pref";

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         if (getFromPref(this, ALLOW_KEY)) {
            showSettingsAlert();
         } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               
               // Should we show an explanation?
               if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                  Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                  showAlert();
               } else {
                  // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                     new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                     MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
               }
            }
      } else {
         openCamera();
      }
      
   }
   public static void saveToPreferences(Context context, String key, Boolean allowed) {
      SharedPreferences myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(CAMERA_PREF, 
         Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
      prefsEditor.putBoolean(key, allowed);
      prefsEditor.commit();
   }
  
   public static Boolean getFromPref(Context context, String key) {
      SharedPreferences myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(CAMERA_PREF, 
         Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      return (myPrefs.getBoolean(key, false));
   }
  
   private void showAlert() {
      AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
      alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
      alertDialog.setMessage("App needs to access the Camera.");
      
      alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "DONT ALLOW",
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               dialog.dismiss();
               finish();
            }
      });
   
      alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "ALLOW",
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               dialog.dismiss();
               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
               new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
               MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
            }
      });
      alertDialog.show();
   }
  
   private void showSettingsAlert() {
      AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
      alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
      alertDialog.setMessage("App needs to access the Camera.");
      
      alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "DONT ALLOW",
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               dialog.dismiss();
               //finish();
            }
      });
   
      alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "SETTINGS",
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               dialog.dismiss();
               startInstalledAppDetailsActivity(MainActivity.this);
            }
      });
   
      alertDialog.show();
   }
  
   @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
      switch (requestCode) {
         case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA: {
            for (int i = 0, len = permissions.length; i < len; i++) {
               String permission = permissions[i];
            
               if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                  boolean 
                  showRationale = 
                     ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                     this, permission);
                  
                  if (showRationale) {
                     showAlert();
                  } else if (!showRationale) {
                     // user denied flagging NEVER ASK AGAIN
                     // you can either enable some fall back,
                     // disable features of your app
                     // or open another dialog explaining
                     // again the permission and directing to
                     // the app setting
                     saveToPreferences(MainActivity.this, ALLOW_KEY, true);
                  }
               }
            }
         }
         
         // other 'case' lines to check for other
         // permissions this app might request
      }
   }
  
   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
   }
  
   public static void startInstalledAppDetailsActivity(final Activity context) {
      if (context == null) {
         return;
      }
   
      final Intent i = new Intent();
      i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
      i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
      i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
      i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
      i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
      context.startActivity(i);
   }
  
   private void openCamera() {
      Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
      startActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

Any help will be largely  Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand your question... If you want to save some data via your application though, and being able to retrieve it in your phone even if you are not online, you can use : window.localStorage

```
window.localStorage.setItem("itemName", item); // to save it in your phone
window.localStorage.getItem("itemName"); // to retrieve your item
```

To update your item, you can use setItem("itemName", item) again.

Does it answer your question ? :)